# $limit and $project for logic calculation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to use ISODate from the earliest timestamp and calculate the age of the document in my collection using todays age. I need to do this for the top 10 documents. I have been able to extract the top 10 documents with the earliest timestamps but I am unable to use that data and do the mathematical calculation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$title" }},
    {$sort:{timestamp:1}}, 
    { $group: 
            {
              _id:"$title",
              test:{$first:"$timestamp"}
            }
    },
    {
     $project:{
            age_Days: { $divide: [{$subtract: [ new Date(), "$test" ] }, (24*60*60*1000)] } ,
            age_Years: { $divide: [{$subtract: [ new Date(), "$test" ] }, (365*24*60*60*1000)] } 
            },

    },
    {$limit:10}
]);
```

Thats what I want my logic to look like but I am only getting "null" answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if someone in the future stumbles upon this problem.

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { $sort: { timestamp: 1 } },
    { $group: { 
            _id: "$title", test:{$first:"$timestamp"} }
            },
    {
     $project:{
            age_Years: { $divide: [{$subtract: [ new Date(), "$test" ] }, (365*24*60*60*1000)] }
            }

    },
    {$sort:{age_Years:-1}}, 
    {$limit:3}
],
{ allowDiskUse : true }
);
```